# Modifing global array of strings from function C

Tags: c, arrays, string, function

I having trouble debugging the folowing code I want to get all items in the hisory 
from processHIstory() functioon but i am getting undesired result

here is what i am tring to do
assume user enters the folowong  ...

```
>> ls
>> pwd
>> clear
```

**then history array will be**

```
histrory= {"ls","pwd","clear"}
```

and  when user wants history like this

```
 >>!!
```

I need all histories to displaylike

```
ls 
pwd
clear
```

**but I am getiing the folowing now**

```
 !!
 !!
 !!
```

what is my problem?please help me.

Here is the git link to my code!
[GIST](https://gist.github.com/mehariShare/3e2d12822734f3ceae8d)

thank you.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `*history++` with `history[i]`?

Comment: @zenith yes, but i get null!

Comment: Where do you get null?

Comment: @zenith from processhistory() function the result are (null)(null)(null) when displayed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect when you do `history[commandsExcuted]=argv[0];` you then go and change the value of `argv[0]` which is a pointer.

What you need to do is allocate memory for the string and copy it into history, perhaps something like:

```
history[commandsExecuted] = malloc(strlen(argv[0]));
strcpy(history[commandsExecuted], argv[0]);
```

Sorry if this doesn't compile, its been a while since I have worked with C/malloc/str* functions.  So much nicer in C++.

**Edit:** Instead of manually calling `malloc` and `strcpy` there is also `strdup`, from the man page:

> The strdup() function returns a pointer to a new string which is a
>   duplicate of the string s.  Memory for the new string is obtained
>   with malloc(3), and can be freed with free(3).

Comment: I am getting null form out put ... when processhistory() is called

Comment: @zenith do you try it with my code, it's not working for me, which line do you modify.

Comment: I copypasted your code, replaced `history[commandsExcuted]=argv[0];` in `processCommand` with the two lines ilent2 proposed, and the history is now showing correctly to me.